# ProGuard exception "Input jars and output jars must be different"

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, proguard

I try run ProGuard from maven plugin and I get error:

```
[proguard] ProGuard, version 5.2.1
 [proguard] java.io.IOException: Input jars and output jars must be different [D:\projects\demoObfuscation\target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar].
 [proguard]     at proguard.ConfigurationChecker.checkConflicts(ConfigurationChecker.java:202)
 [proguard]     at proguard.ConfigurationChecker.check(ConfigurationChecker.java:82)
 [proguard]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:73)
 [proguard]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:538)
```

in proGuard config I have this:

```
-injars /target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-outjars /target/demo-pro.jar
```

**EDIT**:

Minimal POM with plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
        <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
          <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
          </libs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal POM?

Comment: @norbjd I eddit question

Comment: `-injars /target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` should be `-injars target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I think your proguard configuration is not read. Try to configure proguard directly in the plugin :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <injar>demo-${project.version}.jar</injar>
        <outjar>demo.jar</outjar>
        <options>
            <option>-keep public class Main { *; }</option>
        </options>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
        </libs>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
<plugin>
```

`-keep` option is required (put your main class here). You can read more on [`proguard-maven-plugin` documentation](http://wvengen.github.io/proguard-maven-plugin/).